# Explicit formula of Mobius Transformation that maps non intersecting circles to concentric circles

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

How to find a Mobius Transformation that maps the circles $C(0,1)$ and $C(4,2)$  to a pair of concentric circles.

I have already discussed this problem in general case in this blog. By the composition of transformation we can do this. But , the idea I have seems burdensome to calculate. Is there any good way of doing this?

Comment: What is the notation $C(a, b)$? Assuming one entry is the radius, one of the circles $C(0, 1), C(4, 0)$ is degenerate.

Comment: $C(0,1)$ is circle centre at origin and radius $1$

Comment: I edited , $C(4,0)$ was a typo

Comment: By symmetry we may as well assume that the transformation maps the real line to itself, and so we may take the transformation coefficients to be real, and in particular worry only about the four intersections of the circles with the real axis. Then, the problem amounts to finding a projective transformation that maps the four points to a particular configuration.

Comment: This might be messy to do too explicitly, though: Any projective transformation preserves the cross ratio of set of four points, which in this case turns out to be $\frac{15}{7}$. We can use this to conclude that the radii $r_1, r_2$ of the transformed circles satisfy $\left(\frac{r_2 + r_1}{r_2 - r_1}\right)^2 = \frac{15}{7}$, and so the ratio of the radii satisfy $r_2 = \frac{1}{4}(11 \pm \sqrt{105}) r_1$, which is a little ugly...

Answer (score 1):

An affine transformation $az+b$ may be used to turn one circle into the unit circle (specifically, $(z-a)/r$ if the circle has center $a$ and radius $r$). If the other circle is not contained within it, we may apply $1/x$ to (or $-1/x$ if we want to use $\mathrm{PSL}_2\mathbb{R}$), which fixes the unit circle while swapping its interior and exterior.

The transformations that preserve the real line come from $\mathrm{PSL}_2\mathbb{R}$ and the ones that preserve the unit circle are $\mathrm{PSU}(1,1)$. The intersection of these two is $\mathrm{PSO}(1,1)$ whose elements may be represented by

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \cosh\tau & \sinh\tau \\ \sinh\tau & \cosh\tau \end{bmatrix}. $$

Alternatively, one may say $Mz=\tfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$ and solve $M(1)=1$, $M(-1)=-1$ to get $Mz=\frac{az+b}{bz+a}$, without loss of generality $a^2-b^2=1$ whose solutions ($a>0$) are parametrized $(a,b)=(\cosh\tau,\sinh\tau)$.

The circle in the interior of the unit circle intersects at points $u,v\in(-1,1)$. We may parametrize this interval with $\tanh$, say $u=\tanh(\alpha)$, $v=\tanh(\beta)$ and check that

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \cosh\tau & \sinh\tau \\ \sinh\tau & \cosh\tau \end{bmatrix} \tanh(\sigma)=\tanh(\tau+\sigma) $$

using $\tanh$'s sum formula. Therefore, we may choose $\tau=-\frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\beta)$ and apply this transformation to turn $u,v$ into values $x,-x$ within $(-1,1)$, necessarily intersection points of a concentric circle.

Note the transformation may also be written as

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \tanh\tau \\ \tanh\tau & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

and use various hyperbolic trig identities to obtain

$$ \tanh\tau=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+uv-\sqrt{(1-u^2)(1-v^2)}}{1+uv+\sqrt{(1-u^2)(1-v^2)}}} $$

In the case of $C(0,1)$ and $C(4,2)$, we can apply $-1/x$ so the latter becomes $C(-\tfrac{1}{3},-\tfrac{1}{6})$ with corresponding endpoints $u=-\tfrac{1}{2}$, $v=-\tfrac{1}{6}$. Plugging these into the above, rescaling and using Wolfram|Alpha to denest,

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{21}+\sqrt{5} & \sqrt{21}-\sqrt{5} \\ \sqrt{21}-\sqrt{5} & \sqrt{21}+\sqrt{5} \end{bmatrix} $$

preserves $C(0,1)$ and turns $C(-\tfrac{1}{3},-\tfrac{1}{6})$ into $C(0,\tfrac{11-\sqrt{105}}{4})$.