# Question about Mobius Transformation for concentric circles

Tags: circles, transformation

I have several concentric circles with center (0,0) and one eccentric circle which are inside smallest concentric circles with center (d,0), I need to transform all the circles to concentric circles. Joe Manlove had answered similar question:
[Explicit formula of Mobius Transformation that maps non intersecting circles to concentric circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977765/explicit-formula-of-mobius-transformation-that-maps-non-intersecting-circles-to/2239889#2239889)

But I don't know why we should do like this. Is there any recommended reference book to read?

Thanks,
Tang Laoya

updated @ 04/19/2017:
suppose two circles： C1: $|z-d|=r_1$, C2: $|z|=r_2$, where $ 0<d<1$, according to Joe Manlove's answer, we have the following transformation:

$$f(z) = \frac{\frac{z - d}{r_1}+d}{1+d\frac{z-d}{r_1}}=\frac{z-d+r_1d}{r_1+dz-d^2}$$

Now we'll check whether C1 and C2 are concentric circles with center (0,0). For C1, we have $|z-d|=r_1$,
$$|f(z)|^2=\frac{(z-d+r_1d)(\overline{z-d}+r_1d)}{(d(z-d)+r_1)(d(\overline{z-d})+r_1)}=\frac{|z-d|^2+2r_1dRe(z-d))+(r_1d)^2}{d^2|z-d|^2+2r_1dRe(z-d)+r_1^2}=1$$

But for C2: $|z|=r_2$, how to prove that 
$$|f(z)|^2=const$$

Thanks,

Tang Laoya

Comment: You can move _two_ non-concentric circles to concentric circles with a Möbius transformation, but you can't expect to start with two concentric circles and a third non-concentric circle and make all three concentric with a Möbius transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply. Joe Manlove's solution seems to solve my problem, since the transformation is not related to radius of the large circle, that is to say, no matter what value the radius of larger circles is, the transformation is the same. I don't know whether the transformation is correct or not. If it is correct, I need to find a reference book to know the details.

Comment: In my case there is only one circle is non-concentric, i.e., the center is not (0,0), and all other circles are concentric with center (0,0).

Comment: Dear Andrew, do you mean that Joe Manlove's solution is not correct? Thanks

Comment: As far as I know (I didn't carefully check the details), Joe Manlove's solution _is_ correct; my point is, the argument does not generalize to more than two circles, because the conclusion is false for more than two circles. (Precisely, if $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ are concentric circles of positive radius, and if $C_{3}$ is non-concentric, there does not exist a Möbius transformation $T$ such that the image circles $T(C_{1})$, $T(C_{2})$, and $T(C_{3})$ are concentric.)

Comment: Dear Andrew D. Hwang, Thanks for your kindly reply. From Joe's solution, it seems the transformation is not related to $C_2$'s radius, that is to say, if $C_2, C_3$, ... all have the same center (0,0) but have different radius, the transformation is the same, i.e., we can have the same transformation let $C_1$ and $C_2$, $C_1$ and $C_3$, ... be concentric, and after transformation, $C_1$ is the unit circle. Therefore, all $C_1, C_2$, ... are concentric after that transformation. But my question is: how to prove that $|f(z)|=R (const.)$ under $C_2$? Thanks.