# Conformal modulus of a region bounded by $2$ circles.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let a circle of radius $r$ be situated inside another circle of radius $R$. Let $d$ the distance between the centers of these circles, so $0\le d< R-r$. It is known that there exists a [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) transformation that takes these two circles to a pair of concentric circles. While the transformation is not unique, the ratio of the radiuses of these two concentric circles is uniquely determined, so a function of $R$, $r$ and $d$. Could anyone provide a formula for this ratio? References would be very helpful too. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977765/explicit-formula-of-mobius-transformation-that-maps-non-intersecting-circles-to.

Comment: @Martin R: I see, some good comments after that question... so I can reduce to working with segments....Thanks!