# Mobius transformation sending spheres to concentric spheres

Tags: complex-analysis, spheres, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

In the complex plane it is known that given two disjoint circles we can find a Mobius transformation that maps them to concentric circles.

**My question:** Given two disjoint $(n-1)$-spheres $Y$ and $Z$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is there a Mobius transformation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that maps them to concentric spheres or is that not true in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, two circles are symmetric across the real axis, and so the Mobius transformation used to make them concentric is also symmetric across the real axis (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977765/explicit-formula-of-mobius-transformation-that-maps-non-intersecting-circles-to/)).

This generalizes to spheres by symmetry: we can make spheres concentric using a Mobius transformation which is symmetric across the axis of symmetry (of the two spheres); just pick any plane containing this axis, get a 2D Mobius transformation, then extend to rest of space by symmetry.

Comment: So in your answer to that other question you prove that if the circles are symmetric across the real axis then there is a transformation in $PSL_2\mathbb{R}$ that does the trick. In 3 dimensions now what do you mean by the "axis of symmetry of the two spheres"? Also is it true that you can extend any Mobius transformation defined in a plane on the whole $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @MadMax Given any two spheres, there is a line through their centers. Both spheres are symmetric across this axis, so we can call it an axis of symmetry. I think you can technically extend any Mobius transformation of Euclidean space to one on a bigger Euclidean space, but I am talking about the special case of a Mobius transformation that is symmetric across an axis (how to extend these to transformations of bigger spaces is easier to see).

Comment: I don't see why that is easy. Could you explain why? There is a way to extend Mobius transformations defined on planes (called Poincare extension) but I guess that is not what you mean.

Comment: I already said how you extend it: *by symmetry*. If $M(x+yi)=u(x,y)+v(x,y)i$ is a transformation of $\Bbb C$ symmetric across $\Bbb R$ (i.e. $M\overline{z}=\overline{Mz}$, so $M$ is represented by a real matrix), then we can extend it to $\Bbb R\times\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ via $M(x,{\bf y})=(u(x,\|{\bf y}\|),v(x,\|{\bf y}\|)\hat{\bf y})$. Can you visualize this in 3D for instance? Basically, the Mobius transformation would *do the same thing* to every half-plane bounded by the axis of symmetry.

Comment: Another way is to write the transformation as a composition of circular inversions (which is always possible), extend the circles to spheres (in which the circles are great circles), and consider the corresponding composition of spherical inversions.